# Eclipse installer won't make a shortcut to open the program and I have no idea how to open it

Tags: eclipse

I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. I'm trying to install Eclipse via the installer from the official website and that's going fine - but after I finish running the installer I can't close out of Eclipse otherwise I have no way of relaunching it. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse installer asked you during installation where you wished to install Eclipse. If you kept the default parameters then you should have an "eclipse" folder in your home folder that contains your Eclipse install.

For example, for Eclipse Java, you will find everything in `~/eclipse/java-2020-09/eclipse`. It contains the binary file to execute for launching Eclipse.

So for launching Eclipse you can simply use `./eclipse/java-2020-09/eclipse/eclipse` from a terminal.

It might be useful to create a launcher with this command, with Menulibre for example or your flavor's menu editor ;-)